# View in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a table in Sql server, I added some data (Edit 200 rows) and with New Query i Tested this :

`Select * from Table-name`

I could see the data that i have already inserted, when i make a new i Added 3 tables and some fields from them ,and Execute!
but i just see the name of the fields and there is no data in the view. 
what should i do?
Thanks

Comment: `*` is expanded at CREATE VIEW time, not select from view time.

Comment: Well did you add any data?

Comment: If the table was re-created, then it was probably dropped first. So all data that was inserted in the old table would be gone.  But if the table was altered by adding the extra columns, then the old data should still be there.  And you should recreate that `select * ...` view. So that the extra columns are included in it.

Comment: DO NOT use select * in a view. Not only does it not include new columns it can do some really bizarre things if the table changes and you don't refresh the view (sys.sp_refreshview).

Comment: I would go further than @SeanLange and claim you should not use `select *` anywhere at all, except maybe when selecting all columns from a cte.

Comment: @ZoharPeled absolutely. Or when using EXISTS.

Comment: @SeanLange I like `exists(select 1 ....` better, but that's really just a personal preference. I though about using `exists(select 1/0...` just to mess with the heads of the less experienced developers but gave up on this idea :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - I always find select 1 a bit odd to me. I have to stop for half a second and look at it. But as you said just personal preference.

Comment: did you JOIN to 3 additional tables?  Have you verified those other 3 tables have data that matches the join column values?  Can you post the definition of your view?